# Проблемы при поднятии сервера

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - после запуска nodejs, не получается подключится к серверу использую IP и порт, который слушает сервер nodejs. Однако скрипт запускается без проблем.

[image: http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/23_3_2015/18/VV85eUgl90KPCBBrRXuzIw.jpg]

Ошибок в коде нет также, как и в логах. 
В чем может быть ещё причина?

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World!');
}); // <-----------
server.listen(1337);
console.log('Server running on port 8000');
```

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть написали, как пытаетесь обратиться к серверу. Как минимум меня очень сильно смущают эти две строки:

    server.listen(1337); //Сервер слушает 1337 порт

    //??? почему же мы пишем тогда 8000 порт в консоль?
    console.log('Server running on port 8000');

Comment: Лень было исправлять после смены порта)

Comment: @Jeix ну это шедеврально вообще

---

проверьте через netstat, не на 127.0.0.1 ли у вас висит сервер. Должно быть 0.0.0.0.

Comment: @Etki, Хм... там вообще нет информации о данном порте

Comment: @Jeix, значит он вообще не слушает, либо nestat по тем или иным причинам не включил его в вывод. Попробуйте `wget localhost:1337 -` на сервере, если отдает html, то сервак все себе вполне слушает. Можно еще через telnet руками отправить запрос, но это для особых извращенцев.

Comment: @Etki, HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Comment: @Jeix `netstat -an | grep 1337` что выведет?

Comment: @Etki, tcp6 0 0 :::1337 :::*  LISTEN

Comment: @Jeix Он успешно поднялся на ipv6, и я не уверен, что вы можете достучаться к нему по ipv4 (я честно не знаю, мельком глаза видел, что пустой ipv6 адрес должен поддерживать такую возможность, но не уверен в этом). Попробуйте достучаться к нему через ipv6-адрес (он должен быть в выводе ifconfig на eth0 или аналоге).

Answer (score 1):

Получилось решить данную проблему, изменив чуть-чуть конфигурации nginx:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:1337;
}
```

Comment: Ох, сказали бы сразу про nginx - решили бы три часа назад